# Cannot find declaration for Android default library

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I am viewing source code for `android.widget.DayPickerPagerAdapter`, which extends `PagerAdapter`. When I try to go to `declaration` of `PagerAdapter`, it failed by showing `Cannot find declaration to go to`.

`PageAdapter` appears in `red`, which I suspect Android Studio didn't download the appropriate Android's SDK? The same for some other packages.

[image]

Similar problem for some `R.layout..` & `R.styleable..`, it gives no response on clicking `go to declaration`.

[image]

Here's my Project Structure:

[image]

Project build & running on emulator works fine. Just I can't access source code for some Android library packages.

How can I tell Android Studio to download source code for these packages / resources? Thanks!

Comment: Try to import this `import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;`

Comment: Did you try clean and build? Also did you try syncing your project?

Comment: compile support library `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'` in gradle file

Comment: You are trying to access PagerAdapter from com.android,internal.widget.PagerAdapter. But PagerAdapter is not a subclass of any Widget, Check my anser below it will help you @shuwn-yuan-tee

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `PagerAdapter` from `com.android,internal.widget.PagerAdapter`. But `PagerAdapter` is not a `subclass of any Widget`,

from your Import Statements :-

**Remove** `import com.android,internal.widget.PagerAdapter ;`

and

**Add** this  `import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter`;

*It will solve your error while using PagerAdapter.*

Comment: Hi @shuwn-yuan-tee , check this and update me on your results.

Comment: In my question above, the first screenshots is the source for `android.widget.DayPickerPagerAdapter`, which is an Android library, not the class I wrote myself. So I can't change whatever it imports. I am sure the class works without problem, just I can't access source code of some packages that are used by the class. Anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: your library also extends PagerAdapter nothing else , you need to import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter